# How to write Java AudioInputStream to MP3?

Tags: java, javasound

Now I have an AudioInputStream, using the following code I can write it to a WAVE file. While what I want is an MP3 file, what should I do?

```
AudioInputStream ais= new AudioInputStream(bais1, audioFormat, bufferSize);

try {
    AudioSystem.write(ais, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, new File("demoFile.wav")
);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In my project, the cache is not big enough to store big files, which means solution like using a tool to convert WAVE to MP3 is not allowed(WAVE file is too big).

Comment: See the [Java Sound info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info) for details on the SPI.

Comment: The standard Java Sound code doesn't support mp3. There are mp3 decoders that can be added but to the best of my knowledge there are no encoders (until recently mp3 encoders where covered by patents which were expensive to license).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a github library of java audio utilities that include claims of being able to encode mp3.

[pududits.soundlibs](https://github.com/pdudits/soundlibs)

I haven't used the mp3 libraries, only ogg/vorbis decoding. I'd be tempted to try the JOrbis encoder for ogg/vorbis before getting into mp3's.